# Include types from multiple files

Tags: raml

I have a file structure that looks like this:

[image]

This project will contain the api docs for multiple internal apis from microservices.
The idea is to have common types for different apis, and at the same time individual types that are typical for an individual api.

For example I have a common type called 'CoordType.raml':

```
#RAML 1.0 CoordType

type: object
properties:
  lng:
    displayName: lng
    description: geolocation, longitude
    type: number
    format: double

  lat:
    displayName: lng
    description: geolocation, latitude
    type: number
    format: double
```

If I import this in my api.raml file like this:

```
uses:
  CoordType: !include ../common/types/CoordType.raml
```

And use it like this:

```
/trending:
  is: [traits.paged]
  get:
    description: Get trending items
    queryParameters:
      near_lat: CoordType.lat
      near_lng: CoordType.lng
      since: timestamp
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: PostStatType
            example: !include ./samples/GetTrending.json
```

Then it doesn't quite give me the desired result:

[image]

Ideally I would like to just include the common types in the api-specific types file (hence the api.raml file would still only include a single file).
Unfortunately I can't seem to be able to find the right syntax for it, if it is possible at all.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you try having the common request parameters in their own .yaml files & then refer to them from your api.raml files as traits?